# Changing owner of a hadoop cluster on EC2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2

A few months back, I created a hadoop cluster at work on EC2 by using my AWS account. Now that it's stable, I want to transfer the ownership of the cluster to my company account. It has 15 nodes, and the only way I understand it is that I gotta create 15 AMIs and then share those AMIs with the right tags.

Is there a better way to go about this?

My goal is to solely change the owner, I don't want to change the cluster at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. You can share those AMIs (although if all 15 nodes are the same, that will just be one AMI you instantiate 15 times?) with another AWS account ID. This is the best way to go about it.

To get full 'ownership' of the image to your company account, they would need to use your shared image to spin up an EC2, and then make their own AMI from it which they'll then own.

Answer (score 0):

I think MonkeyMatrix has it right, theres not many cross account sharing options. Two points i can add though: First its a long shot but depending on how much you use your account for other stuff you could always just transfer the account ownership to your company and start a new one for yourself. (I've done this before)

If you do have to go through the hassle of recreating id recommend you work with cloudformation, depending on how complex your setup is. It will save a lot of effort if your company wants to move to a third account, for test/dev etc loads. Its also useful to be able to store your architecture in a scm.